# Official reference for Google Spreadsheet Api Structured Query syntax

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm looking for the official reference for the query syntax used for creating *structured queries* for requesting rows in the Google Spreadsheet API, as discussed [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#sending_a_structured_query_for_rows)

The only example given is:

```
 GET https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/worksheetId/private/full?sq=age>25%20and%20height<175
```

There must be some references of the query syntax used somewhere?

In particular I want to know how to query for all rows (containing column `a` and `b`) for which `val(a) != val(b)`

Comment: I think that is it. Your "here" link is the best documentation I have seen. .... ListDemo.java is also worth a look http://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn-history/r497/trunk/java/sample/spreadsheet/list/ListDemo.java

Comment: Thanks. With Google spreadsheets it's sort of as if I'm in a timemachine having to search for solid documentation in a pre-web era...