# Filter Google Sheets based on the value in a column

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I need to read a Google Sheet using the Sheets API. I can fetch all the rows, however since those rows are in tens of thousands and will continue to grow, I need to find a way to filter them without fetching all the rows.

I just need a SQL WHERE clause with an equality condition for one or more columns. For example, there's a phoneNumber column which is column C in the sheets. I just need to fetch the rows where this column has values equal to some value.

I am currently using the [Google Sheets V4 API for Node.js](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets). I was using the [get api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get), but since it just has `range` as the only filter option available, I thought of trying [getByDataFilter api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/getByDataFilter) assuming it provides some way to filter the data.

Unfortunately, the only good way in `getByDataFilter` API is to use [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#GridRange) in [DataFilter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DataFilter). This still doesn't allow me to provide any condition to filter the data except using rows and/or column ranges.

So is there any way to do it without fetching all the rows? I can't modify that particular sheet. The only way I can find out now is to have a cron job run at midnight to sync the data with a database and then query the database.
Is there any better way to filter the data?

Comment: Google Sheets API is not meant to provide database functionality, it is meant to provide UI functionality to programs: read https://stackoverflow.com/a/37868852/9337071 If you know the values to display, you could try programmatically adding a `BasicFilter`, querying row metadata to determine which are hidden, `batchGet` the non-hidden rows, and then clear the `BasicFilter`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458708/php-google-sheets-api-v4-filter-by-column-value-and-return-relevant-rows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176515/googlesheet-api-php-filter-query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463608/how-to-handle-structured-queries-for-retrieving-rows-with-google-sheets-api-v4 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732784/official-reference-for-google-spreadsheet-api-structured-query-syntax Website: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/filters

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google visualization Query directly on the url:

If your url is

```
docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id
```

and you want `Select A,sum(B) group by A`,
Use:

```
docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id/gviz/tq?tq="your encoded query here"  
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r8_mfnZAvTFmT02JHi1XgOwn_-sLCR9XgmR8wEQ4uW4/gviz/tq?tq=select%A%2C%20sum(B)%20group%20by%20A
```

---

- [tq Authorization](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#Authorization) (Not needed, If Spreadsheet is set to "Anyone with link can view")
- [Query 0.7 Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)